# Question concerning Python short notation

Tags: python

Is there something like the following in Python:

```
def function(a, b):
  ...

function(3 if something, b if something else c)
```

That is, are there statements or expressions I can use to conditionally pass different argument values to a function *inline*

Comment: Are you looking to shorten an if/else statement?

Comment: There's conditional expressions. Maybe that's what you mean. I can't tell from what you've posted.

Comment: You would just need an `else` value for the first parameter, the second parameter is valid as you wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good python values readability, so you'd probably want to write

```
if something:
    function(3)
elif something1:
    function(b)
else:
    function(c)
```

but you *could* write

```
function(3 if something else (b if something1 else c))
```

but please don't.

Comment: Is that what the OP is asking for? Their function requires two arguments.

Comment: You could (but shouldn't) place two ternary statements inside the function call. You really shouldn't though.

Comment: My brain parses that comma as natural-language grammar, not python. But you have a good point. Let's see. (In any case, if you take the comma as Python-grammar, then the expression cannot be parsed.)

Comment: it's for code golfing, I would never do this in normal coding

Comment: @HeinrichBrack if you're code golfing, consider `[[c,b][something1],a][something]` (both `something`s would have to be strictly boolean, because `0==False`, `1==True`)

Answer (score 0):

[Ternary Operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) looks very similar.. Mild advice though on not placing it inside a function call as it makes things pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The most Pythonic way to implement this would be to assign those if statement return values to variables and then call the function based on those variables.

You might be interested to learn about list comprehensions that allow for if statements when creating a list. Checkout this example from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]

newlist = [x for x in fruits if "a" in x]

print(newlist)

['apple', 'banana', 'mango']
```